# How to hide scrollbar from animated image which is larger than screen width without affecting the body?

Tags: jquery

So for example, if i have an image of width 2000px whic is larger than screen width, animated from left to right. [Here.](http://jsfiddle.net/x2YGX/) How do i code it so that a scroll bar wont appear when it is animating? Also it won't affect my body for example when i restore down the window a scroll bar will appear for my body only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just changing `position` to `fixed` will also do

```
#a {
    width: 2000px;
    position: fixed;
 }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x2YGX/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to wrap the element in a wrapper that basically "eats" the excess width:

**JavaScript**:

```
$('#a').wrap($('<div />', {'class': 'wrapper'}));
```

**CSS**:

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;

    height: 200px;  /* .wrapper collapses if there is no height
                       and your elements are absolutely positioned */
}​
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/x2YGX/3/**

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS `overflow`

```
.animation
{
/*other properties*/
overflow:hidden;
}
```